# Trying to make a binary search tree, but I keep getting invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference errors

Tags: go, null-pointer

I'm trying to create a BST, add a node, and print the data in that node, but I keep getting invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference errors. I know something is wrong with my pointers, and I've been fiddling around with them all afternoon, and I can't seem to get it right. Could someone please take a look and let me know what stupid mistake I'm making?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    data  int
    left  *node
    right *node
}

type root struct {
    root *node
}

func (bt root) addNode(n *node, data int) {
    if n == nil {
        newNode := node{
            data:  data,
            left:  nil,
            right: nil,
        }
        n = &newNode
        fmt.Println("Works")
    } else if data < n.data {
        bt.addNode(n.left, data)
    } else {
        bt.addNode(n.right, data)
    }
}

func main() {
    tree := root{root: nil}

    tree.addNode(tree.root, 6)
    fmt.Println(tree.root.data)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Cps4Y5mqYFM

Comment: The assignment `n = &newNode` in `addNode` overwrites the contents of the variable `n` which is an argument to the method and hence is a local variable in it. The result of this assignment is therefore not visible in the caller because the assignment had modified the copy of the caller's variable. Hence `tree.root` remains `nil`, which you could have easily seen if you have printed that value. To modify a pointer-typed variable in a function, you has to pass it a pointer to that pointer and derefence it when assigning—like in `*ptrToPtr = someAddress`.

Comment: To say that in other words, when you call `tree.addNode(tree.root)` the contents of the variable `tree.root`, which is `nil`, is copied into the local variable `n` of the `addNode` method, and then that method overwrites the content of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

As kostix correctly pointed out, in order to modify my tree with that method, I had to pass in a pointer to a pointer to the original tree. Thanks, kostix!

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    data  int
    left  *node
    right *node
}

type root struct {
    root *node
}

func (bt root) addNode(n **node, data int) {
    if *n == nil {
        newNode := node{
            data:  data,
            left:  nil,
            right: nil,
        }
        *n = &newNode
        fmt.Println("Works")
    } else if data < (*n).data {
        bt.addNode(&((*n).left), data)
    } else {
        bt.addNode(&((*n).right), data)
    }
}

func main() {
    tree := root{root: nil}

    tree.addNode(&(tree.root), 6)
    fmt.Println(tree.root.data)
}
```